# Getting an undefined error when trying to change state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

In the below code I'm trying to change the variables i, x, y, and z through the use of `setstate()`, but I keep getting an error saying that the variables i, x, y, and z are "undefined." Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this might be happening?

```
state = {
albumArt: [
  {title: "Supermodel", image: "AlbumImages/1.jpg"},
  {title: "A Moment Apart", image: 'AlbumImages/2.jpg'},
  {title: "Beerbongs and Bentleys", image: 'AlbumImages/3.jpg'},
  {title: "Another Eternity", image: 'AlbumImages/4.jpg'},
  {title: "Astroworld", image: 'AlbumImages/5.jpg'},
  {title: "The Story of Us", image: 'AlbumImages/6.jpg'},
  {title: "Slow Motion", image: 'AlbumImages/7.jpg'},
  {title: "Free Spirit", image: 'AlbumImages/8.jpg'},
  {title: "Birds in the Traps Sing McKnight", image: 'AlbumImages/9.jpg'},
  {title: "At. Long. Last. A$ap", image: 'AlbumImages/10.jpg'}
],

  otherStateI: 0,
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  z: 0 }

randomAlbum = () => {
this.setState(i = Math.floor(Math.Random() * 10));
this.setState(x = Math.floor(Math.Random() * 10));
this.setState(y = Math.floor(Math.Random() * 10));
this.setState(z = Math.floor(Math.Random() * 10)); }
```

Comment: You need to use `this.setState({x : Math.floor(Math.Random() * 10)})`

Comment: Your have error in `this.setState`. It should be as @Code Maniac said. See [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) for more usage.

Comment: And it is `Math.random()` not `Math.Random()`

Answer (score 0):

For your state, you need to pass `setState` an object with the props/values you want to change (or a function that returns the object)

```
this.setState({ i: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) });
// ...etc
```

In your particular code it would also make more sense to pass them all at once:

```
this.setState({ 
    i: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
    x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
    y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
    z: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
});
```

Oh and PS - it's `Math.random()` not `Math.Random()` - I've corrected it for you here :)